# is there a limit in -ctime for a find?

Tags: find, date

I am trying to find all folders older than 5 years old to remove them.

```
find . -type d -ctime +1800 -print
```

Just as a test yields no returns, it seems like there is a limit on what can be passed to ctime?  Is this the case? or is my formating off?

Comment: There's no limit and your command is correct. What makes you think that there should be some results? It's not that common to have a directory where no file has been created, moved or removed in five years, and that has not been moved or restored from backup. Do note that neither the ctime nor the mtime of a directory tells you anything about when the content of files in that directory has changed.

Comment: because I have a ton of folders that ls as this:  `drwxrwxr-x  3 apache apache  53248 Apr  9  2005 53466` . (folder name is 53466) .  ... so wanted to know how to find these folders... maybe mtime is what I really want? that seems to grab the folders that are 5 years and older.

Comment: If you've ever moved the files to a different disk (except by copying the whole partition), that resets the ctime, but if done right it preserves the mtime.

Comment: ahhhh so I probably want to go by the mtime?